# Jquery sliding panel using animate positioning issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue, nav

I am trying to create a navigation panel that consists of 3 list items. When a list item is clicked, a corresponding set of links (subnav) slides out to reveal itself.

I have a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/M8fS3/2/

In this demo, the technique works, but it is a bit buggy. The close button and (+) button seem to lose their place the more you click a link. They seem to  lose their relative positioning, and act as if they are absolutely positioned, relative to the container, not their parent.

I would like to go about writing this in a different way, or see if any fellow devs have a better technique to accomplish this same task. Currently my jquery is as follows:

```
$("#serviceBox li a").on("click", function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'left' : -250
        }, {duration: 200, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});

        $(this).next(".panel").animate({
            'left' : 0
        },  {duration: 200, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    });

    $("a.closePanel").on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().animate({
            'left' : 250
        },  {duration: 200, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});

        $(this).parent().prev("a").animate({
            'left' : 0
        },  {duration: 200, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    });
```

I am setting the queue to false because I want the animations to be in synch with each other.  Let me know if you would like to see the HTML and CSS here (that is currently on the fiddle). THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the close and open buttons were losing their positioning is because they were inheriting the relative value of the parent container, which overrode their absolute positioning. Simply adding `position:relative` to `#serviceBox li .panel a.closePanel` fixed it!